# Using Microsoft Business One Drive Connector license among various users

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Hello I am developing a Power Apps application. One of its  functionalities is to take pictures and upload to a One Drive  directory. To do that I plan to use the OneDrive Business Connector with the same One Drive user shared among all the powerapps users( around 100). My question is if that is possible.  For what I read in the Throttling specifications I understand the answer as a yes, but limited to 100 api calls per minute. I want to check with some some of you guys if you already made something similar. Thanks.

Comment: With that you mean I have to buy a one drive to each one of the Power apps users?

Comment: If that is the case, it doesn't make sense. They are not going to consume the space, they only go to upload drives to a central drive.